# C Shrinking size of circular buffer

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to finish up a circular buffer program that simply holds an array of stock quotes. However, I cannot seem to get my output correct when shrinking the circular buffer.

The condition for shrinking the buffer is if 3/4 of the space in the buffer is free, shrink the buffer by 1/2. My code for shrinking/enlarging is as follows:

```
void cbuf_update(cbuf *cb_ptr, unsigned int time, double rate){
    int threeFourths;
    threeFourths = (cb_ptr->maxSize/4)*3;

    if((cb_ptr->maxSize != startSize) && cb_ptr->freeSlots >= threeFourths){
        printf("Shrinking!\n");
        int newSize;
        newSize = (cb_ptr->maxSize/2)-1;
        cbuf *newBuffer = malloc(sizeof(cbuf) + newSize * sizeof(quote));
        newBuffer ->maxSize = (cb_ptr->maxSize/2);
        newBuffer ->freeSlots = newBuffer->maxSize - (cb_ptr->maxSize - cb_ptr->freeSlots);
        int x;
        int counter;
        int y;
        counter = 0;
        if(cb_ptr->end > cb_ptr->start){
            for(x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->maxSize; x ++){
                if(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time != -1){
                    newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].time = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time;
                    newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].rate = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate;
                    counter ++;
                }
            }   
            for(y = 0; y < cb_ptr->start; y++){
                if(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time != -1){
                    newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].time = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time;
                    newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].rate = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].rate;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(cb_ptr->end < cb_ptr->start){
            //printf("second condition\n");
            for(x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->start; x ++){
                if(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time != -1){

                    newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].time = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time;
                    newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].rate = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate;
                    counter ++;
                }
            }       
        }
        newBuffer->start = counter;
        newBuffer->end = 0;
        cbuf_dump(newBuffer);
        *cb_ptr = *newBuffer;       

    }


    if(cb_ptr->freeSlots == 0){
        printf("EXPANDING CIRCULAR BUFFER!\n");
        int newSize;
        newSize = (cb_ptr->maxSize * 2) - 1;
        cbuf *newBuffer = malloc(sizeof(cbuf) + newSize * sizeof(quote));
        newBuffer->maxSize = cb_ptr->maxSize * 2;
        newBuffer->start = cb_ptr->start;
        newBuffer->end = cb_ptr->end;
        newBuffer->freeSlots = newBuffer->maxSize - cb_ptr->maxSize;
        int x;
        int counter;
        counter = 0;
        for(x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->maxSize; x ++){
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].time = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time;
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].rate = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate;
            counter ++;
        }
        int y;
        for(y = 0; y < cb_ptr->start; y ++){
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].time = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time;
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].rate = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].rate;
            counter++;
        }
        newBuffer->start = cb_ptr->maxSize;
        newBuffer->end = 0;

        *cb_ptr = *newBuffer;



    }   


    //If the start pointer has reached the end of the array and there are still free slots back at the beginning of the array, loop back.   
    if(cb_ptr->start == cb_ptr->maxSize && cb_ptr->freeSlots > 0){
        //printf("Cannot insert time: %d\n", time);
        cb_ptr->start = 0;
    };
    cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[cb_ptr->start].time = time;
    cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[cb_ptr->start].rate = rate;
    cb_ptr->start = cb_ptr->start +1;
    cb_ptr->freeSlots = cb_ptr->freeSlots -1;

    //If any quote in the array is older than 5 minutes when compared to the current quote, flag it as null and move the end pointer up one.
    //Also, clear up a freeSlot.
    int x;
    for(x = cb_ptr->end; x < (cb_ptr->start); x ++){

        if((time) - (cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time) >= fiveMin){
            cb_ptr->end = cb_ptr->end + 1;
            cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time = -1;
            cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate = -1.00;
            cb_ptr->freeSlots = cb_ptr->freeSlots +1;
        }
    }


}
```

Code for dumping the buffer (printing it) is as follows:

```
void cbuf_dump(cbuf *cb_ptr){
    printf("*****\t DUMPING \t*****\n");

    if(cb_ptr->start > cb_ptr->end){
        //printf("first dump cond.\n");
        printf("start: %d\t end:%d\n", cb_ptr->start, cb_ptr->end);
        int x;
        for(x = cb_ptr->end; x<(cb_ptr->start); x++){
            printf("%d.) time = %d, \t rate = %f\n",x,(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time),(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate));
        }
    }

    /*
    If the start pointer has been wrapped back around to the beginning of the circular buffer, then the end pointer must be at an index that is         greater than the start index. For this, we need to print out the data ranging from the end pointer to the end of the array, and then the        data from the start pointer to the end pointer provided the data isn't flagged as null (having -1 for both entries in the quote struct).
    */
    if(cb_ptr->end >= cb_ptr->start){
        //printf("Secondary condition\n");
        int x;
        for(x=cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->maxSize; x ++){
            printf("%d.) time = %d, \t rate = %f\n",x,(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time),(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate));
        }
        int y;
        for(y = 0; y < cb_ptr->start; y ++){
            if(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time != -1){
                printf("%d.) time = %d, \t rate = %f\n",y,(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time),(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].rate));
            }
        }
    }

    //printf("freeslots = %d\n", cb_ptr->freeSlots);
}
```

and finally, my main is:

```
int main(){

    cbuf *cb1 ;

    cb1 = cbuf_init() ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 60, 1.291) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 63, 1.287) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 63, 1.231) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 69, 1.229) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 72, 1.247) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1,361,1.291);
    cbuf_update(cb1, 411, 1.291) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 412, 1.281) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 413, 1.292) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 414, 1.284) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 414, 1.290) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 511, 1.241) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 512, 1.251) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 513, 1.232) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 514, 1.202) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 517, 1.119) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 551, 1.080) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 552, 1.081) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 553, 1.079) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 554, 1.088) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 561, 1.072) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 562, 1.113) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 563, 1.091) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 564, 1.092) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 571, 1.089) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 572, 1.073) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 573, 1.061) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 574, 1.111) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 581, 1.119) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 582, 1.123) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 583, 1.151) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 584, 1.153) ;  
    cbuf_dump(cb1);
    cbuf_update(cb1, 750, 1.200) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 818, 1.210) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 868, 1.230) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 878, 1.230) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 900, 1.240) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 2000, 1.240) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    return 0;

}
```

The output towards the end should be:

```
*** Circular Buffer Dump ***
size = 11, max = 40
start = 19, end = 29

19: time = 571,  rate = 1.089000
20: time = 572,  rate = 1.073000
21: time = 573,  rate = 1.061000
22: time = 574,  rate = 1.111000
23: time = 581,  rate = 1.119000
24: time = 582,  rate = 1.123000
25: time = 583,  rate = 1.151000
26: time = 584,  rate = 1.153000
27: time = 750,  rate = 1.200000
28: time = 818,  rate = 1.210000
29: time = 868,  rate = 1.230000
****************************

Shrinking circular buffer: old max = 40, new max = 20


*** Circular Buffer Dump ***
size = 8, max = 20
start = 3, end = 10

3: time = 581,  rate = 1.119000
4: time = 582,  rate = 1.123000
5: time = 583,  rate = 1.151000
6: time = 584,  rate = 1.153000
7: time = 750,  rate = 1.200000
8: time = 818,  rate = 1.210000
9: time = 868,  rate = 1.230000
10: time = 878,  rate = 1.230000
****************************

Shrinking circular buffer: old max = 20, new max = 10


*** Circular Buffer Dump ***
size = 5, max = 10
start = 1, end = 5

1: time = 750,  rate = 1.200000
2: time = 818,  rate = 1.210000
3: time = 868,  rate = 1.230000
4: time = 878,  rate = 1.230000
5: time = 900,  rate = 1.240000
****************************



*** Circular Buffer Dump ***
size = 1, max = 10
start = 6, end = 6

6: time = 2000,  rate = 1.240000
****************************
```

However, my output keeps finishing up like this:

```
*****    DUMPING    *****
start: 30    end:19
19.) time = 571,     rate = 1.089000
20.) time = 572,     rate = 1.073000
21.) time = 573,     rate = 1.061000
22.) time = 574,     rate = 1.111000
23.) time = 581,     rate = 1.119000
24.) time = 582,     rate = 1.123000
25.) time = 583,     rate = 1.151000
26.) time = 584,     rate = 1.153000
27.) time = 750,     rate = 1.200000
28.) time = 818,     rate = 1.210000
29.) time = 868,     rate = 1.230000
*****    DUMPING    *****
start: 31    end:23
23.) time = 581,     rate = 1.119000
24.) time = 582,     rate = 1.123000
25.) time = 583,     rate = 1.151000
26.) time = 584,     rate = 1.153000
27.) time = 750,     rate = 1.200000
28.) time = 818,     rate = 1.210000
29.) time = 868,     rate = 1.230000
30.) time = 878,     rate = 1.230000
Shrinking!
*****    DUMPING    *****
start: 9     end:8
8.) time = 900,      rate = 1.240000
Shrinking!
*****    DUMPING    *****
start: 2     end:1
1.) time = 2000,     rate = 1.240000
```

Obviously the formatting is different, but the numbers should match up. I cant quite figure out why as soon as the time of 900 is added to my buffer, it seems to think the time codes 581-878 are all greater than five minutes away from 900 (the criteria for printing is only printing the most recent quotes in a 5 minute timespan). I realize 581-600 are obviously going to be discarded, but the rest should still remain in the buffer.

Comment: If this is the continuation [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291212/copy-elements-from-c-array-into-a-different-array) you need to take stock in that answer first, because right now the `*cb_ptr = *newBuffer;` just copies the structure base (sizes, counts etc) from you new buffer to your old one, then leaks the new one.

Comment: Please study how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). You've not given the data structures, so we have to reverse engineer them; you've not given definitions of `fiveMin`, `startSize`, `cbuf_init()`. It appears you're using a flexible array member, which is good. You are, however, reassigning the value passed into the `cbuf_update()` function, but you can't modify the value in the `main()` because you would have to pass a `cbuf **cb_dblptr` into the function to modify that. A debugging `malloc()` or [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) would help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { startSize = 0 };
enum { fiveMin = 5 * 60 };

typedef struct quote { int time; double rate; } quote;

typedef struct cbuf { int maxSize; int freeSlots; int start; int end; quote quoteBuffer[]; } cbuf;
static void cbuf_dump(cbuf *cb_ptr);

static void cbuf_update(cbuf **cb_dblptr, unsigned int time, double rate)
{
    cbuf *cb_ptr = *cb_dblptr;
    int threeFourths = (cb_ptr->maxSize/4)*3;

    if (cb_ptr->maxSize != startSize && cb_ptr->freeSlots >= threeFourths)
    {
        printf("Shrinking!\n");
        int newSize;
        newSize = (cb_ptr->maxSize/2)-1;
        cbuf *newBuffer = malloc(sizeof(cbuf) + newSize * sizeof(quote));
        newBuffer->maxSize = (cb_ptr->maxSize/2);
        newBuffer->freeSlots = newBuffer->maxSize - (cb_ptr->maxSize - cb_ptr->freeSlots);
        int counter = 0;
        if (cb_ptr->end > cb_ptr->start)
        {
            for (int x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->maxSize; x++)
            {
                if (cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time != -1)
                    newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter++] = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x];
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < cb_ptr->start; y++)
            {
                if (cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time != -1)
                    newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter++] = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y];
            }
        }
        if (cb_ptr->end < cb_ptr->start)
        {

            for (int x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->start; x++)
            {
                if (cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time != -1)
                    newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter++] = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x];
            }
        }
        newBuffer->start = counter;
        newBuffer->end = 0;
        cbuf_dump(newBuffer);
        *cb_dblptr = cb_ptr = newBuffer;
    }

    if (cb_ptr->freeSlots == 0)
    {
        printf("EXPANDING CIRCULAR BUFFER!\n");
        int newSize;
        newSize = (cb_ptr->maxSize * 2) - 1;
        cbuf *newBuffer = malloc(sizeof(cbuf) + newSize * sizeof(quote));
        newBuffer->maxSize = cb_ptr->maxSize * 2;
        newBuffer->start = cb_ptr->start;
        newBuffer->end = cb_ptr->end;
        newBuffer->freeSlots = newBuffer->maxSize - cb_ptr->maxSize;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->maxSize; x++)
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter++] = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x];
        for (int y = 0; y < cb_ptr->start; y++)
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter++] = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y];
        newBuffer->start = cb_ptr->maxSize;
        newBuffer->end = 0;
        *cb_dblptr = cb_ptr = newBuffer;
    }

    if (cb_ptr->start == cb_ptr->maxSize && cb_ptr->freeSlots > 0)
        cb_ptr->start = 0;
    cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[cb_ptr->start].time = time;
    cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[cb_ptr->start].rate = rate;
    cb_ptr->start = cb_ptr->start +1;
    cb_ptr->freeSlots = cb_ptr->freeSlots -1;

    for (int x = cb_ptr->end; x < (cb_ptr->start); x++)
    {
        if ((time) - (cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time) >= fiveMin)
        {
            cb_ptr->end = cb_ptr->end + 1;
            cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time = -1;
            cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate = -1.00;
            cb_ptr->freeSlots = cb_ptr->freeSlots +1;
        }
    }
}

static void cbuf_dump(cbuf *cb_ptr)
{
    printf("*****\t DUMPING \t*****\n");

    if (cb_ptr->start > cb_ptr->end)
    {
        printf("start: %d\t end:%d\n", cb_ptr->start, cb_ptr->end);
        for (int x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->start; x++)
        {
            printf("%d.) time = %d, \t rate = %f\n",x,(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time),(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate));
        }
    }

    if (cb_ptr->end >= cb_ptr->start)
    {
        for (int x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->maxSize; x++)
        {
            printf("%d.) time = %d, \t rate = %f\n",x,(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time),(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate));
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < cb_ptr->start; y++)
        {
            if (cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time != -1)
            {
                printf("%d.) time = %d, \t rate = %f\n",y,(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time),(cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].rate));
            }
        }
    }
}

static cbuf *cbuf_init(void)
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(cbuf));
}

int main(void)
{
    cbuf *cb1;

    cb1 = cbuf_init() ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 60, 1.291) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 63, 1.287) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 63, 1.231) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 69, 1.229) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 72, 1.247) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1,361,1.291);
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 411, 1.291) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 412, 1.281) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 413, 1.292) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 414, 1.284) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 414, 1.290) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 511, 1.241) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 512, 1.251) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 513, 1.232) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 514, 1.202) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 517, 1.119) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 551, 1.080) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 552, 1.081) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 553, 1.079) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 554, 1.088) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 561, 1.072) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 562, 1.113) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 563, 1.091) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 564, 1.092) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 571, 1.089) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 572, 1.073) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 573, 1.061) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 574, 1.111) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 581, 1.119) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 582, 1.123) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 583, 1.151) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 584, 1.153) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1);
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 750, 1.200) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 818, 1.210) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 868, 1.230) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 878, 1.230) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 900, 1.240) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    cbuf_update(&cb1, 2000, 1.240) ;
    cbuf_dump(cb1) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I note that this code runs into problems according to `valgrind`.  However, I suspect that is due to the lackadaisical allocation in `cbuf_init()` — at least in part.  Note that this code uses structure assignments.  There was a time when they were not supported by C compilers; however, it was a very long time ago, in the dim dark recesses of the last millennium (and more than 10 years before the end of it) that was a problem.

Comment: +1 I hope [the preamble to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291212/copy-elements-from-c-array-into-a-different-array) was at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: One issue is `int threeFourths = (cb_ptr->maxSize/4)*3;` which should be written with the multiplication first: `int threeFourths = (3 * cb_ptr->maxSize)/4;`.  However, if I add `assert(counter < newSize);` after the copying loops in the expand code, the assertion fires.  There's a problem there to be addressed (by the OP, I think).

Comment: Yeah, I barely looked at his algorithm, I just made sure the introduction of the by-addr param and internalizing what used to be the param didn't break anything (I don't think it did). Not the way I would necessarily code a circular buffer, but the OP's needs are probably different than mine.